# how moq respository to test Iqueryable dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

part of code I wanted mock

```
var myvar = await Repository.Query.GetAll()
                .Include(c => c.product)
                .Where(c => c.id == id)
                .ToArrayAsync();
```

And Repository have this interface and i mock TReadRepository and TWriteRepository

```
public IRepository<TReadRepository, TWriteRepository> Repository { get; }
```

I always have the same error

The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

my test

```
[Test]
        public async Task teste01()
        {
            //Arrange
            var objCartaoFake = FixtureRecursive().Build<myCartao>()
                .With(x => x.Id, 1)
                .Create();
            
            
             ConfigureCartaoDbSet<myCartao>(new List<myCartao{objCartaoFake});
            
             var ReadRepository = new Mock<ICartaoReadRepository>();
             ReadRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll())
                 .Returns( new EnumerableQuery<myCartao>(new List<myCartao> {objCartaoFake}));
                
            
            //Act
            var result = await CartaoAppService.VincularCartoesFilhos(1);

            //Assert
        }
```

and my configuration of ConfigureCartaoDbSet

```
public static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateDbSetMock<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements) where T : class
        {
            var elementsAsQueryable = elements.AsQueryable();
            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            
            mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
                .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(elementsAsQueryable.GetEnumerator()));

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()
                .Setup(m => m.Provider)
                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(elementsAsQueryable.Provider));
            
            // mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.GetEnumerator());
  
            return mockSet;
        }

public static void ConfigureCartaoDbSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : class
        {
            var listMock = CreateDbSetMock(list);
            var context = new Mock<CartaoContext>(null, null);
            context.Setup(x => x.Set<T>()).Returns(listMock.Object);
        }
```

Comment: How does your mock look like?

Comment: I updated my question with more information